# Install magento 2 extension without ssh

Tags: magento2

I need to install several extensions. I don't have SSH to that host so I need to be able to do everything with FTP + magento 2 backend.

So far I've copied the extension files on the /app/ dir.

Looking at extension istructions i see this:

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

There is a way to accomplish this in another way? Installing extensions in Magento feels really cumbersome and awkward compared to other CMS like Wordpress or Drupal.

*Update*
I found an article that suggests to do this:

```
Edit app/etc/config.php file and three line code:
‘Ves_All’ => 1,
‘Ves_Megamenu’ => 1,
‘Ves_Setup’ => 1,
```

But I have no clue what is that and I haven't found so far any info about those options.

Answer (score 1):

Make a new php file Let say "updater.php" and paste following code in it (add php tags at start n end of file).

```
  system('php bin/magento setup:upgrade');
  system('php bin/magento cache:flush');
  system('php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy');
```

We are using system() function to run PHP SSH commands.

Upload this file in your Web root and access it using

http://yourdomain/updater.php

You will see output of commands after few seconds

Answer (score 0):

If you can upload file to your server, you can use my file to run magento command line 
[image]
<strike>Realy sorry!I cannot upload php file here. So you can down it on this page</strike> http://www.mageoneplus.com/how-to-run-magento-command-line-without-ssh-access.html

```
<div class="mageoneplus">
    <div class="header"> Welcome to ssh command line</div>
    <div class="body">
        <?php 
            if(isset($_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'])){
                $url = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
            }elseif(isset($_SERVER['PATH_INFO'])){
                $url = $_SERVER['ORIG_PATH_INFO'];
            }
        ?>
        <form action="<?php echo $url; ?>" id="mageoneplus-ssh" method="post" >
            <div  class="run-ssh">Example: php bin/magento</div>
            <div class="input">
                <?php
                    $value = "php bin/magento ";
                    if(isset($_POST["command"]) && $_POST["command"]){
                        $value = $_POST["command"];
                    }
                ?>
                <input type="text" style="width:600;"  name="command" id="command"  value="<?php echo $value ?>"  placeholder="Enter command line here..." />
            </div>
        </form> 
        <button type="submit" form="mageoneplus-ssh" value="Submit">Run</button>
        <div class="result">
            <?php
                if(isset($_POST["command"]) && $_POST["command"]){

                    try{
                        $output = null;
                        set_time_limit(0);
                        $str = $_POST["command"];
                        exec($str, $output);
            ?>

            <h1>The result:</h1>
                <ul class="result-text">
                    <?php
                        foreach($output as $op){
                    ?>
                        <li><?php echo $op; ?> </li>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </ul>
            <?php

                    } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo 'you must <a href="https://www.google.com/search?q=enable+exec">enable exec</a>';
                    }
                }           
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="author">
        <div>Written by <a href="http://mageoneplus.com">Louis Pham</a></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
    .mageoneplus{ padding:20px; }
    .header , .body ,.author{padding:10px 0px; }
    .run-ssh{ margin:10px 0px; }
    .result-text{ max-height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;}
</style>
```